# How to efficiently reuse Ionic page against different providers?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm working with Ionic 2 and I have entity management page which is suitable for different data providers.
Now I have page for character management.

```
export class CharacterListPage{
  currentItems: Character[];

  constructor(public provider: Characters) {
    this.currentItems = this.provider.query();
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

I need to do creature management. Creatures structure is identical to character structure.
Obvious way is just copy-paste page and make some renaming:

```
export class CreatureListPage{
  currentItems: Character[];

  constructor(public provider: Creatures) {
    this.currentItems = this.provider.query();
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

Is it possible to use more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a typical use case for an abstract class, luckily typescript brings that feature to the .js world:

You have a base class, lets call it `ListPage`, which holds all the common functionality of a `Character` and a `Creature` which can then be extended by other pages and *reuse* this existing functionality:

```
class ListPage { 
  listItems: Character[] | Creature[]; 

  constructor(provider: Characters | Creatures) { 
    this.listItems = provider.query(); 
  } 

  // other common methods 
} 

class CharacterListPage extends ListPage { 
  constructor(provider: Characters) { 
    super(provider); 
  } 
} 

class CreatureListPage extends ListPage { 
  constructor(provider: Creatures) { 
    super(provider); 
  } 
}
```

For this minimal example it may not seem very efficient but when your classes get more complex and have much common functionality it will be very useful.
[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) you can find the documentation on typescript classes.

Comment: There were couple Ionic specific problems but principally this answer solves the problem.